# Adding list of lists without duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to merge two nested lists. I have a LatLng class which contains two properties, Latitude and Longitude - both are doubles. This class is brought in from a NuGet package called DotNetCoords. A line is represented as an array of LatLngs, and I have a number lines in a network that are represented below:

```
IEnumerable<LatLng[]> lineNetwork;
```

I have another network of lines that I want to add to this one but exclude duplicates, currently I have tried distinct but I don't think LatLng is equatable so this doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried the below which doesn't work either.

```
IEnumerable<LatLng[]> lineNetwork; 
IEnumerable<LatLng[]> newLineNetwork;  

lineNetwork.AddRange(newLineNetwork.Where(x => !lineNetwork.Contains(x)));
```

It would need to check that ALL coordinates in the line are not equal before adding it. So for example:

```
LatLng[] line1 = { 
new LatLng(Latitude: 0.1, Longitude: 0.1),
new LatLng(Latitude: 0.2, Longitude: 0.2),
new LatLng(Latitude: 0.3, Longitude: 0.3)
}
LatLng[] line2 = { 
new LatLng(Latitude: 0.1, Longitude: 0.1),
new LatLng(Latitude: 0.2, Longitude: 0.2),
new LatLng(Latitude: 0.3, Longitude: 0.3)
}
LatLng[] line3 = { 
new LatLng(Latitude: 0.1, Longitude: 0.1),
new LatLng(Latitude: 0.4, Longitude: 0.4),
new LatLng(Latitude: 0.5, Longitude: 0.5)
}
```

Where Line1 & Line3 would be added but not Line2 as all coordinates are shared with Line1.

Comment: You have to provide a way to determine if two instances of `LatLng` are equal. E.g. implement `IEqualityComparer<LatLng>`.

Comment: Yea that's what I'm asking for assistance with @HimBromBeere

Comment: You might want to look into creating an `EqualityComparer<T>` that can be used to tell various methods how to decide if two things are equal.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Note: once you've created your EqualityComparer it can be passed to the contains method that you are trying to use to make it work as you expect. Here's the MSDN for that overload: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to implement `IEqualityComparer` in order to compare two instances of `LatLng` and than use [`IEnumerabe<T>.Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx). However as you have an **array** of that type, you also need the comparer to work on that array-type:

```
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<LatLng[]>
{
    public bool Equals(LatLng[] x, LatLng[y])
    {
        return a.SequenceEquals(y, new MyLatLngComparer(0.001));
    }
    public int GetHashCode(LatLng[] x)
    {
        return x.First().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

As the `LatLng`-class has no own implementation for equality, you have to provide your own within `SequenceEquals`:

```
class MyLatLngComparer : IEqualityComparer<LatLng>
{
    private readonly double Tolerance;
    public MyLatLngComparer(double tolerance) { this.Tolerance = tolerance ;}
    public bool Equals(LatLng x, LatLng y)
    {
        return Math.Abs(x - y) <= Tolerance;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(LatLng x)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Here you see how to compare floating-point values. Equality for those types should allways be implemented by some small tolerance as shown above, in order to avoid rounding-issues.

Finally you can use `Distinct` with the provided comparer:

```
lineNetwork.AddRange(newLineNetwork.Distinct(new MyComparer()));
```

I also omitted some null-checks for brevity. You should in particular check if your array even has an element, e.g. within `MyComparer.GetHashCode`.

Comment: Unless there is something that I've missed that would make it a bad idea its probably worth noting that the OPs original code would work with the new comparer: `lineNetwork.AddRange(newLineNetwork.Where(x => !lineNetwork.Contains(x, new MyComparer())));`. I think your use of Distinct will still allow in items that are already in `lineNetwork` to be added again.

Comment: @Chris You´re right, `Contains` would also work. But I´m not sure what you mean by your last sentence. Did I miss any check?

Comment: As Chris mentioned, Distinct couldn't have been used but overall this is an amazing detailed answer and works really well. Thank you guys!

Comment: The OPs original code said that if an item in `newLineNetwork` was already in `lineNetwork` then it would not be added in. Your use of distinct does not account for that. Though I note that you might want both since the OPs original code seemed to rely on the fact that `newLineNetwork` doesn't contain duplicates (rightly or wrongly).

Answer (score -1):

Three possible options:

1. Extend `LatLng` and override Equals and GetHashCode
2. Implement `IEquatable<LatLng>` as mentioned before (similar to the previous option, but more efficient)
3. Use the linq code you shown, but add an extension method to implement the `Contains` operation (your code fails because the `Contains` tries to search the equality based on the object reference. The only way is to override the Equals method)

Comment: Obviously the class is from a 3rd-party lib, so option 1 and 2 can´t be implemented.

Comment: You can always create a new class that inherit from that one, that's not a problem at all. Unless the class is sealed, [which seems is not the case](https://github.com/AndyCW/OSGridReference/blob/67032223edbcc9d74294cc60a5259df44a90ccdd/DotNetCoords/LatLng.cs#L40)